# Ionic 5 Deeplinks No Match Found

Tags: javascript, cordova, deep-linking, ionic5, angular10

I am developing a project with Angular 10/Ionic 5 on Cordova. I implemented deeplinks as shown in https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks. Here my app.component.ts and package.json

```js
this.deeplinks.route({
        // register which routes and will be handled
        '/password': 'ResetPassword',
      }).subscribe(match => {
        // navigate to route if it matches
        console.log('found!');
        if (match.$route === 'ResetPassword') {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/forget-password']);
          });
        }
      }, nomatch => {
        console.log(nomatch.$link);
      });
```

```js
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "myapp",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "myapp.com.tr",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "C:/Program Files/Git/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
```

When I try to go to "myapp://app/password" it gives No Match found error with

> {"path":"/password","queryString":"","fragment":"","host":"app","url":"myapp://app/password","scheme":"myapp"}

Can you please tell me what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Use should have '/password' in your app.routing.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Try a full URL instead:

```
myapp://myapp.com.tr/app/password
```